# Fetch Current Google Sheet URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to mail the current google sheet URL like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19sig7bVj6m247Gxap92Bc7-eb5TAMn4NQng9k_Zsqrk/edit#gid=0`. My code in `Code.gs` is like below.

```
var TO_ADDRESS = "abcd@gmail.com";
var sendEmailTo = (typeof TO_ADDRESS !== "undefined") ? TO_ADDRESS : mailData.formGoogleSendEmail;
if (sendEmailTo) {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: String(sendEmailTo),
        subject: "Contact form submitted",
        htmlBody: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()  //this is not working
      });
    }
```

How can I fetch current google sheet URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl()

if (sendEmailTo) {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: String(sendEmailTo),
        subject: "Contact form submitted",
        htmlBody: url
      });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Other readers could learn if you add some explanation to your code.